# Asynchronous function that run in a given time interval in c# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, visual-studio-2022

In my visual studio, windows application project I have a function `getSensorApiData()` which is used to retrieve data and saving to database. I want to run this function in every given seconds to update data without affecting other running functions in the project. I used the following code.

```
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            getSensorApiData();
        });
```

But when I use this code some other functions in the project not working properly. Help me to solve this problem..

Comment: do you mean  to call getsensorapi every 3 seconds?

Comment: *"some other functions in the project not working properly."* -- Can you give more details? What is the problem with the other functions?

Comment: Did the answers below help you?

Comment: I have a window which shows the update. When I use this code, that function not reloading. When I remove this it works fine.

Comment: So did you solve the problem? Can you show the code about showing the update window? The message given so far doesn't seem to solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I solved the problem using the same code placed in different place. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var timer = new Timer(Callback, null, 0, 3000);

    //Dispose the timer
    timer.Dispose();
}
static void Callback(object? state)
{
    //Your code here.
    _=DoAsync();
}
private async Task DoAsync()
{
    await getSensorApiData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This exact solution I needed a while back.

I execute the method in a new thread and control the delay inside the method being called.

This how I seperated its execution in independent thread without disturbing the rest of code.

```
new Thread(async () => await bnb.GetDataset()).Start();
```

And this is how I make sure it is being called at specific intervals i.e 1 sec.

```
public async Task GetDataset()
{
  while (true)
  {
    //your code...
    await Task.Delay(1000);
  } 
}
```